# Play's evolution is not running on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, scala, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.1

I followed the [Scala Play 2.1.x tutorial](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/ScalaTodoList) to created a todolist application.

On local development environment + local Heroku Postgres: The evolution is executed automatically. The app works perfectly fine.

On Heroku, the evolution is not executed at all. Therefore, I will get a relation does not exist error.

Here is the `Procfile`:
`web: target/start -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL} -Ddb.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -DapplyEvolutions.default=true`

**Attempts**

1. Move `db.default.url`, `db.default.driver` & `applyEvolutions.default` to `application.conf`.
2. Used instructions from the accepted answer in this question [Errors in evolutions on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195568/errors-in-evolutions-on-heroku). Connected to the remote Heroku Postgres DB from my local development machine and run the evolution - it works perfectly.
3. I installed Play 2.2.1 and attempted the same tutorial, I encounter the same problem.

Since I am able to execute evolutions from my local dev machine onto the remote Heroku Postgres DB. The problem seems to happen only when it is on the Heroku environment.

Comment: Try removing the `-DapplyDownEvolutions.default=true` from your `Procfile`

Comment: Removed `-DapplyDownEvolutions.default=true`, but still doesn't solve the problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a very bad mistake - the evolution script was gitignored. Which means it was never deployed to Heroku, so there was nothing for Play's evolutions to execute.

To be exact, the evolution script, `*.sql`, was gitignored by my global gitignore setting. The `.gitignore` that came with `play new appname` works perfectly fine.

Comment: This was my exact problem, thank you. To go a step further, I added this entry to my .gitignore and the play evolution sql ONLY is included now: !conf/evolutions/**/*.sql

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is not from Heroku but from your database in Heroku.

Do you have the a table called "play_evolutions" in your database?
What is your ebean conf for Heroku?

Comment: Hi! Nope, I cannot find the `play_evolutions` table in the database, which is supposed to keep track of the evolutions. And nope, not using ebean for the app.

Comment: I followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195568/errors-in-evolutions-on-heroku. Connect to the remote database from my local machine, and the evolution works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I copy my working version posted in

[Heroku - Unable to setup postgres database through Play Framework app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237351/heroku-unable-to-setup-postgres-database-through-play-framework-app/33438865#33438865)

In my case git init, git add ., works great. Using play 2.4, Slick 3.0.3 & postgres in Heroku it works for me the following setup that runs my sql evolution scripts:

in build.sbt:

```
name := """app-name"""
```

and add the following in libraryDependencies ++= Seq(

```
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "1.0.1",
"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "1.0.1",
"com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.0.3",
"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc41",
"org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4",
```

in application.conf:

```
slick.dbs.default.driver ="slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource"
slick.dbs.default.db.properties.driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
```

and in Procfile:

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/app-name -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -Dplay.evolutions.db.default.autoApply=true
```

Cheers

Comment: Sorry, I've rewriten the answer. Thks for the comment. Cheers